# How to extract a LONG data to any text datatype in Oracle 8i Enterprise edition?

Tags: sql, oracle, types, long-integer

How to extract a LONG data to any text datatype and insert it into another table in Oracle 8i Enterprise edition?

Comment: 'Convert' is a bit vague. What are you trying to do - change a column's data type in a table ([e.g. to LOB](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e18294/adlob_long_lob.htm))? Extract a long value [as a LOB](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions205.htm)? Manipulate a long value in PL/SQL? Something else?

Comment: I want to concatenate that column with other fields

Comment: You could see if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34610410/convert-long-to-varchar-in-oracle/34610411#34610411) helps